# @RequestBody Annotation In Spring/Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my controller class of my Rest application I have used `@RequestBody` to get the data provided.
But I noticed that while passing the data via postman, if form-data is used to pass the data I do not need `@RequestBody` and my application executes fine. But when I pass the data through raw option of postman that's when I am required to use the annotation.
Could you please explain what `@RequestBody` does?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @RequestBody annotation maps the HttpRequest body to a transfer or domain object, 
enabling automatic deserialization of the inbound HttpRequest body onto a Java object.

Spring automatically deserializes the JSON into a Java type assuming an appropriate one is specified. 
By default, the type we annotate with the @RequestBody annotation must correspond to the JSON sent from our client-side controller.